# Find a double digit prime divisor of $3^{303} + 2^{404}$ and $3^{303} - 2^{404}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Just to clarify, it's a prime divisor for $3^{303} + 2^{404}$ and a different one for $3^{303}-2^{404}$.

With no sensible sensible way of attacking this problem in sight, I started making a table.
Since the prime divisors have to be double digit numbers, I started at 11.
I used Fermat's Little Theorem to reduce exponents and make the calculations easier.
(edit: everything in the table is $\mathrm{mod\ }p$ of course)

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
p & 3^{303} & 2^{404} & 3^{303} + 2^{404} & 3^{303} - 2^{404}\\
\hline
11 & 5 & 5 & 10 & 0\\
13 & 1 & 9 & 10 & \\
17 & 6 & 16 & 5 & \\
19 & 12 & 9 & 2 & \\
23 & 16 & 3 & 19 &
\end{array}
$$

Although I have found one of the solutions, it's clear that brute force won't be of much use any further, an intelligent method is required.
So what's the proper way of finding the divisor?

Also, I wrote a program to check it case by case, the answer is

> 43.

Comment: HInt: Write $3^{303} \pm 2^{404} = 27^{101} \pm 16^{101}$.

Comment: @lhf Thank you, I noticed that earlier, but for some reason I completely disregarded that observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave a solution for $3^{303}-2^{404}$; the other one is very similar.

$$
3^{303}-2^{404}=27^{101}-16^{101}=(27-16) \sum_{i=0}^{100} 27^i 16^{100-i} = 11 k \tag*{$k \in \mathbb{Z}$}
$$

Thus, $11 \mid \left(3^{303}-2^{404}\right)$.

Since $11$ is prime and it's a double digit number, we're done.

Comment: @TheBestMagician Actually, not at all. Read the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If p must divide $3^{303}+2^{404}$ and $3^{303}-2^{404}$ the it must divide:

$(3^{303}+2^{404})(3^{303}-2^{404})=[(3^6)^{101}-(2^8)^{101}]=$

$(3^6-2^8=473=43\times 11)\sum^{100}_{i=1}(3^6)^i(2^8)=11\times 43$

So 11 and 43 are the solutions.